# getting an error while using time sleep method in python

Tags: python, time, import, weblogic, sleep

There is a weblogic python script that takes a thread dump and sleeps for 10 or 20 seconds then takes another one after time.sleep(30), thread dumps are working fine, but the sleep method time.sleep(20) is not working.

Tried both `import time` and `from time import sleep` as well.

Getting this error below

```
AttributeError: java package 'weblogic.time' has no attribute 'sleep'
```

Answer (score 10):

This one worked for me :
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3560679

```
import time as systime
systime.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the `weblogic.time` package is shadowing the stdlib `time` module. So, when you try to `import time`, you're getting the former, not the latter.

(And `weblogic.time` has nothing in it but a subpackage or module `weblogic.time.common`, so you get an error trying to use its `sleep` function. But that's probably a good thing—better than it had a function named `sleep` that didn't do what you expected.)

If you were developing `weblogic` itself, I could explain how to not do that… but if you're just using `weblogic`, that's not going to help you.

If you're doing something like `from weblogic import *` earlier, the solution is simple: Just don't do that. Otherwise… it will be more complicated to work around.

But if all you need to do is block your interpreter thread for 20 seconds, you can do that with the Java `Thread.sleep(20000)`. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html), but really, you don't need to know much more than that the Java method takes integer milliseconds instead of float seconds. And then you don't need `time`.

Comment: Could he resolve this with the `as` keyword? Like `import weblogic.time as webtime`?

Comment: @thegrinner: That won't help. That will give him `weblogic.time` under the name `webtime`, and then `import time` will give him `weblogic.time` again under the name `time`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to shadow it, I am developing weblogic script,

Comment: @ameya: You already know how to shadow it. You're doing it in your code. You want to know how to _not_ shadow it. If it's a problem in your code or configuration, great, but I can't help without knowing your code and configuration. If it's a problem in weblogic, you just need to create a minimal reproducible test case and file a bug with Oracle.

Comment: @abarnert , I am not doing anything like "from weblogic import *"

Comment: @abarnert can you give me an example of how to not shadow, then probably, i can work it out for my code ???

Comment: The way to prevent it from being shadowed is to rename the `weblogic.time` module to something other than `time` ... But that's probably easier said than done.

Comment: @ameya: There are multiple ways to shadow things. If you add `weblogic` to the `sys.path` at runtime, or to the `python.path` in the property file, any `weblogic.foo` will shadow top-level `foo`. If you `from weblogic import *`, at least with earlier versions of Jython, the same thing will happen. And so on. The only answer is to figure out which one of those things you (or weblogic) are doing, and not do it.

Comment: is there a way, where i can use a different sleep method in python, that doesn't get stuck by weblogic.time ???

Comment: Or, if that's not possible, you need some kind of hacky workaround. Since I don't know Jython nearly as well as CPython or PyPy, and know even less about WebLogic, I probably won't be able to help with that, but hopefully someone else can. The key is to identify exactly what the problem is so you can ask a question that will attract the right jython expert…

Comment: @ameya: Ah, that's a better question. Just use Java's `Thread.sleep` instead! Let me update the answer.